# how to make two form in each other

Tags: c#, winforms

how can i make two form in each other,i mean when i click a button on a form,another form come up,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
```

**Update**
It seems like you want want Kent's answer. Here it a little more flushed out.

In Form1 one you want

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string whatsTheValue="";
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                whatsTheValue = frm.TheValue;

            MessageBox.Show(whatsTheValue);

        }
```

In Form2

```
     public string TheValue {get;set;}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.TheValue = this.textBox1.Text;
        this.Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: In a Button1_Click() on Form1

Comment: just to clarify. Form1.Button opens up Form2. From2.Button returns to Form1 or does it create a new form1? Also what happens to form2 (closes, invisible, sent behind form1)

Comment: form2.buton save something in the textbox i will make it in form2 and then return to form1 to use the value in that textbox

Comment: in this form when i click the form1.button form1 comes again and when i close it,it shows a window with ok button,whats the problem?thanks

Comment: @arash. To clarify in From1.ButtonClick, Form1 is displayed on frm.ShowDialog()?

Comment: @Conrad Frix:no it didnt display in frm,when i click the button in form1 it open another form1 and when i close it it shows frm with just an ok button

Answer (score 2):

```
button.Click += delegate
{
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: that could also be `button.Click += (s,e)=>form2.ShowDialog();`